# Web Service Reference not working in Windows Service application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-services

Mine is Windows Service project. But I've to use a web service in it which is working fine in Web application when I refer it.So I tried to add the web reference into my Windows Service project. It added fine. But the DISC file and wsdl file not being displayed. And also I was not able to use the webservice class reference in my application.

Any solution for accessing that web service in Windows Service app? Or I've to do anything else to make it work

Comment: Are you using .NET 4 Framework, or .NET 4 Client Profile? Make sure you are using the former.

Comment: @DavidP Actually I dont know .NET 4 Client Profile.. Its Visual Studio 2010 am using. So I believe its full framework

Comment: I think @DavidP was asking what framework you are targeting.  Look in your project's property pages in the Application tab and see what the target framework is.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Am using 4.0. But I had no Idea whats 4.0 client profile..